# Using commands inside control templates within resource dictionaries- good or bad?

Tags: wpf

I have defined a control template inside resource dictionary.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.PrintCommand, 
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource    
Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
```

I am using relative source to get the data context and access the viewmodel.

In PrintViewModel

```
public ICommand PrintCommand { get; set; }
```

In Usercontrol, I set datacontext=PrintViewModel

Its working for me. But is it bad practice?

Since this can be consumed by user controls only due to the use of  relative source ,making it conditional that a usercontrol is up the tree and defines a particular command?

would like to know some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether or not it is bad practice, but if I were you i would try a different approach.

If your Button is situated within the UserControl they should share DataContext. If they aren't, you could simply define a DataContext for the Button, not really the best choice either.
A second option would be to bind by using an Elementname and the Path.
Like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName="UserControlsName", Path="PrintCommand}">
```

This requires you to give your UserControl a name e.g: `<UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl"/>`
and it should be in the same XAML-file.